# How to hide the dependencies' shared library in a higher level shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, autotools, automake, pkg-config

I want to build a library,which including my code and the dependencies.
I dont't want to linking the dependencies' shared library when use
the new build library , 
but i can't figure out how to merge the dependencies' shared libraries
and my code's shared library into one higher level shared library . i
used the gnu autotools for the library build system.

Answer (score 0):

figure out  by myself , pkg-config file have the Requires variable can do it